# Adobe CQ: Java error- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not find helper- not able to find handlebar helper

Tags: java, templates

I am getting below error on Adobe CQ template while rendering a handlebar template on client-side

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not find helper: 'if_gt'
>   {{#if_gt data.item.num_comments 5}} ... {{/if_gt}}

Below is the handlebar template which is failing to render

```
{{{{rawBlock}}}}
    <ul class="comment-container"></ul>

    <script id="comment-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each data.item}}
            <li class="comment-copy">
                <h2>
                    {{this.firstName}} {{this.lastName}}<span class="separator">|</span>{{this.address}}<span class="separator">|</span><time datetime="2016-10-01" pubdate="true">{{this.dateCreated}}</time>
                </h2>
                <p>{{this.content}}</p>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
    <div class="load-more-blogs load-more"></div>
    <script id="loadmore-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#if_gt data.item.num_comments 5}}
            <form action="/lm/the-taste-collection/blog/loadmore/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="xref_id" value="{{data.item.xref_id}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="pages" value="6-26">
                <a href="" class="submit" data-wt="true">LOAD MORE</a>
            </form>
        {{/if_gt}}
    </script>
{{{{/rawBlock}}}}
```

Below is the handlebar registration code.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_gt', function (a, b, opts) {
    if (a > b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Note: This piece of code is run on Adobe CQ 6.2 platform

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs the Handlebars helper **must** also be implemented server side as an OSGi Service.

> Custom helpers must be implemented on the server-side as well as the client-side, especially when passing data.  For SCF, most templates are compiled and rendered on the server-side as the server generates the HTML for a given component when the page is requested.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/communities/scf/handlebars-helpers.html#Server-side